# Inserting a string into an SQL query to change the order with PHP

Tags: php, sql, regex, sqlite, preg-replace

I want to insert a 'COLLATE NOCASE' before each ORDER BY clause of an SQLite query.
This is what I have so far:

```
     $string = preg_replace('~(ORDER\s+BY\s+`?.+`?)\s+([ASC|DESC]?)~iU', '$1 COLLATE NOCASE $2', $string);
```

The output is:

> SELECT `x`, `y` FROM `test` ORDER BY `x` COLLATE
>   NOCASE ASC, `z` ASC LIMIT 0, 10

The first instance is matched and replaced. The second instance is not replaced (because of the ORDER BY clause in the pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex into:

```
$query = "SELECT `x`, `y` FROM `test` ORDER BY `x` ASC, `z` ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = preg_replace('~(ORDER BY|,)(\s+\S+)\s+(?=ASC|DESC)~iU', ' $1$2 COLLATE NOCASE ', $query);
echo $query,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT `x`, `y` FROM `test` ORDER BY `x` COLLATE NOCASE ASC, `z` COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```